# T430 Fingerprint Reader won't log me in

Tags: gnome, login, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I just installed fingerprint GUI on my T430 Laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome and it works pretty well. 
I tried different things like getting root and they worked.

Unfortunately I can't login using the fingerprint reader.
When I click my profile I get asked for my password and the fingerprint reader turns on. After I move my finger above it the light turns green indicating the fingerprint got recognized but nothing happens at all. So I have to type my password manually.

Do you have any idea how to fix that? Do I have to make some configs in gnome?

Comment: Does this happens on first login? Do you have your disk encrypted?

Comment: Happens on every login since i installed fingerprint gui. My disk is not encrypted. There is an option to store Keychain password on an usb stick. Do i need this to enable fingerprint login?

Comment: I think that worth a try, please share your experience when you made it work!